# How to populate option select with nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like the following:

[image]

I need to have the option menu populate as follows:

```
<option value="3">Mini</option>
<option value="4">MiniO</option>
```

I tried to do this, but got an error:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/grab_accessories/" + style_id,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == null) {
        } else {
          $("#accessory_box").show();
          console.log(response);
          $.each(response, function(accessory) {
            $.each(accessory, function(id, name) {
              $('#ticket_accessories')
               .append($("<option></option>")
               .attr("value",id)
               .text(name)); 
            });
          });
        }
      }   
    });
```

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '5' in styles
```

Answer can be `js` or `jquery`

Comment: What error did you got? Anything in console?

Comment: Sorry see above for the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the HTML structure you wanted as a string (where `styles` is the array from your example):

```
styles.map(function(obj) {
  return "<option value='"+ obj.id +"'>"+ obj.name +"</option>"; 
}).join();
```

Addition to the answer:

```
success: function(response) {
  if (response == null) {
  } else {
    $("#accessory_box").show();
    var styles = response.styles;
    var options = styles.map(function(obj) {
      return "<option value='"+ obj.id +"'>"+ obj.name +"</option>";
    }).join();

    $('#ticket_accessories').append(options);
  }
}
```

One benefit of this solution is that when looping (and creating option element) with .each, you'll end up accessing and appending elements to DOM on every iteration unless you explicitly build a string out of them. This appends elements only once with all the populated elements.

And it's pure JS, but feel free to use $.map(), if you need extended browser compatibility.

Comment: Hi where would this code go in the context of my code above... to access styles

Comment: You didn't have that piece of code when I was writing this :).

See my addition to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using only one `$.each` since you're building each option for every object you don't need another loop for the properties of the object.

```
var styles = response.styles;

 $.each(styles, function(accessory) {
          $('#ticket_accessories')
               .append($("<option></option>")
               .attr("value",styles[accessory].id)
               .text(styles[accessory].name)); 
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rP5t5/1/)

Comment: Hi I think this answer is good, but for some reason it does not work with response instead of args. Perhaps there is a difference in the array type.

Comment: Yw the only needed changes is to put on the each the array of object styles.